# How to compare arrays of char in CUDA C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, char

I need a function in cuda that recieves an array of chars and if they match, the function returns a value, but when i test this code, always return 0, like none of these conditions match. so far i tried this:

```
__device__   float operate_1(float num, char  func[]) {

        if(func[0] == 's' && func[1] == 'i' && func[2] == 'n'  )

            return sinf(num * PI/180.0);

        else if(func[0] == 'c' && func[1] == 'o' && func[2] == 's'  )

            return cosf(num * PI/180.0);

        else if(func[0] == 'l' && func[1] == 'o' && func[2] == 'g'  )

            return logf(num);

       else if(func[0] == 'e')

            return expf (num);

        return 0; }
        //evaluates an operator.
```

and this code too, but doesn't work like the previous one.

```
  __device__   float operate_1(float num, char  func[]) {

        if(func == "sin")

            return sinf(num * PI/180.0);

        else if(func == "cos")

            return cosf(num * PI/180.0);

        else if(func == "log")

            return logf(num);

       else if(func == "e")

            return expf (num);

        return -0; }
        //evaluates an operator.
```

what i can i do?

Comment: This looks wrong - are you parsing code on the GPU side of cuda, if so why? The first example should work, if you have remembered to upload you char array into cuda-mem.

Comment: i'm parsing this way because i have a math function saved in a structure (i have no problem evaluation simple operation like  a simple sum or a multiplication), but i need to evaluate many different values for the ecuation faster than the cpu could do.

Comment: Oh never mind, yes the first code works, i forgot i had another function that checks if is an operator or a function. thank you!
But really it should be another way more easy to compare, what if i have a really big array?

Comment: in K&R there is a strcmp algorithm implementation, basically a for loop over the two arrays that are being compared. You could just write such a function, ints also in string.h strcmp, I don't remeber if thats in cuda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
__device__ int my_strcmp(const char *str_a, const char *str_b, unsigned len = 256){
  int match = 0;
  unsigned i = 0;
  unsigned done = 0;
  while ((i < len) && (match == 0) && !done){
    if ((str_a[i] == 0) || (str_b[i] == 0)) done = 1;
    else if (str_a[i] != str_b[i]){
      match = i+1;
      if (((int)str_a[i] - (int)str_b[i]) < 0) match = 0 - (i + 1);}
    i++;}
  return match;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry Ricky Dev I made a mistake in rejecting your edit.