# Add char arrays in cuda

Tags: arrays, cuda, char, addition

I am trying to add 2 char arrays in cuda, but nothing is working.
I tried to use:

```
char temp[32];
strcpy(temp, my_array);
strcat(temp, my_array_2);
```

When I used this in kernel - I am getting `error : calling a __host__ function("strcpy") from a __global__ function("Process") is not allowed`

After this, I tried to use these functions in host, not in kernel - no error,but after addition I am getting strange symbols like `ĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶĶ`.

So, how I can add two ( or more ) char arrays in `CUDA` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, how I can add two ( or more ) char arrays in CUDA ?

write your own functions:

```
__device__ char * my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src){
  int i = 0;
  do {
    dest[i] = src[i];}
  while (src[i++] != 0);
  return dest;
}

__device__ char * my_strcat(char *dest, const char *src){
  int i = 0;
  while (dest[i] != 0) i++;
  my_strcpy(dest+i, src);
  return dest;
}
```

And while we're at it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600879/how-to-compare-arrays-of-char-in-cuda-c/19602075#19602075) is `strcmp`

Comment: Okey, everything look nice, but just one problem - I am adding different length arrays, and I dont know from which `pos` i should add  and what is array 'len'. How can I solve this?

Comment: I've fixed the code so they more or less duplicate the functionality of c++ `strcat` and `strcpy`.  This is pretty basic C code.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message explains, you are trying to call host functions ("CPU functions") from a global kernel ("GPU function"). Within a global kernel you only have access to functions provided by the CUDA runtime API, which doesn't include the C standard library (where `strcpy` and `strcat` are defined).

You have to create your own `str*` functions according to what you want to do. Do you want to concatenate an array of chars in parallel, or do it serially in each thread?

Comment: So how I can add 2 char arrays?

Comment: @Eddwhis You have to create your own `strcat` kernel to run in the GPU.